# ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor Syntax question

Tags: asp.net, syntax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

This question appear when I worked with partial view (MVC3/Razor), but I am sure - it's clear Razor Syntax question, not related direct to partial view.
So - I have partial view Menu.cshtml with full markup as:

```
@model IEnumerable<SportsStore.WebUI.Models.NavLink>
@foreach(var link in Model)
{
    @Html.RouteLink(link.Text, link.RouteValues);
}
```

No problem - "parent" view call it @{Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Nav");} and all work as magic.
But, if I will edit the Menu.cshtml as:

```
@model IEnumerable<SportsStore.WebUI.Models.NavLink>
@foreach(var link in Model)
{
    Html.RouteLink(link.Text, link.RouteValues);
}
```

(see - NO '@' before Html.RouteLink!) all just broke: now @{Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Nav");} output is totally empty, no one HTML tag.

Want to know - what is the difference between two piece of code? I assume **@** before **foreach** also automatically "drop into" and apply to **Html.RouteLink** as well? So - am I wrong?

Comment: You sir, are my hero.  I'm working through the same SportsStore article it seems, but I'm converting to VB.Net on the fly.  The conversion between C# and VB is usually trivial, but with Razor it can be tricky.  I was having the same issue with RouteLink not creating output, it seems VB.Net suffers the same flaw (read: applies the same logic)... I added the `@` and everything clicked into gear again.  THANK YOU @Smarty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The @ before the statement causes it to be written to the output stream. When you remove it, all you are doing is invoking a method call on the Html object.

The @-operator's purpose is two-fold. It can either be used to output an expression to the response stream like you see it used in the first example. The other function is to start a code block. You can see this second behavior used in your code example with the `@foreach(var link in Model)`

Comment: That is it! Now I confident with @ operator. :)

Answer (score 3):

The `Html.RouteLink` method simply returns an `IHtmlString` containing a link; it doesn't do anything else.

When you write `@Html.RouteLink(...)`, you're printing this link to the page.
When you write `Html.RouteLink(...)`, you're calling the method without doing anything with the link.
Thus, nothing happens.

Comment: Very good explanation, thanks a lot! It's a pity I can't mark both Answers with green mark.